# 422 error trying to save json data to the database

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to save data to my MySql db from a Node method. This includes a field called `attachments`.

`console.log(JSON.stringify(post.acf.attachments[0]));` returns:

```
{
  "ID": 4776,
  "id": 4776,
  "title": "bla",
  "filename": "bla.pdf",
  "filesize": 1242207,
  "url": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/bla.pdf",
  "link": "https://example.com/bla/",
  "alt": "",
  "author": "1",
  "description": "",
  "caption": "",
  "name": "bla",
  "status": "inherit",
  "uploaded_to": 0,
  "date": "2020-10-23 18:05:13",
  "modified": "2020-10-23 18:05:13",
  "menu_order": 0,
  "mime_type": "application/pdf",
  "type": "application",
  "subtype": "pdf",
  "icon": "https://example.com/wp-includes/images/media/document.png"
}
```

This is indeed the data I want to save to the db:

```
await existing_post.save({
    ...
    attachments: post.acf.attachments[0],
)};
```

However, the attachments field produces a 422 server error (if I comment out this field, the other fields save without a problem to the db). I'm not getting what is causing this error. Any ideas?

I've also tried

```
await existing_post.save({
    ...
    attachments: post.acf.attachments,
)};
```

but then it seems to just save `"[object Object]"` to the database.

The field in the database is defined as text. I've also tried it by defining the field as json, but that made no difference.

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.table("posts", function (table) {
        table.longtext("attachments");
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you provide some details about the `existing_post.save` method ? I don't know it as knex native feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [422](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) error code is about the server unable to process the data you are sending to it. In your case, your table field is `longtext` when `post.acf.attachments` seems like an object. That's why it saves `[object Object]` to your db (It is the return value of the `toString()` method).

Try using

```js
await existing_post.save({
    ...
    attachments: JSON.stringify(post.acf.attachments),
)};
```

MySQL and knex both support the JSON format, I'd suggest you change the field to `json`. (See [knex docs](https://knexjs.org/#Schema-json) and [mysql 8 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)). You'll stiil need to stringify your objects tho.

EDIT: I just saw that Knex supports [jsonInsert](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-jsonInsert) (and plenty other neat stuff) as a query builder that should be useful for you.
Mysql also support a large range of [cool stuffs for handling jsons](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

In addition, when you fetch the results in the database, you'll need to parse the JSON result to get an actual JSON object:

```js
const acf = await knex('posts').select('acf').first();
const attachment = JSON.parse(acf.attachment;
```

Knex also provide [jsonExtract](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-jsonExtract) that should fill your needs (See also the [mysql json_extract](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)

Comment: Thanks, that indeed solved it perfectly and I've changed the db field to `json`! I am having difficulty though to access the data from the db in my React app and was therefore hoping to ask a quick follow-up question. Suppose a db field named `attachment` contains the following data: `{"a": "-", "b": "-", "c": "-"}` and `post` is the database record. How to then access the value for `a`? I've tried `post.attachment.a` and `post.attachment['a']` but both return `undefined`, while `post.attachment` returns `{"a": "-", "b": "-", "c": "-"}`.

Comment: try to log `typeof post.attachment`. My guess is that will give you `string`. You need to parse the result of your query with `JSON.parse(post.attachment)`

Comment: Yes, it indeed returned `string`. I am indeed able to get the value for `a` using `JSON.parse(post.attachment).a`.